Hamiltonian in optimal control
Hamiltonian  $~H~$ (control theory) is:
\begin{align*}
  {H}(\vec{x}~,\vec{\lambda},~u,t)=\vec{\lambda}^T\vec f(\vec{x}~,u,t)+L(\vec{x}, u,t)
 \end{align*}
For Zermelo's navigation problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_navigation_problem
\begin{align*}
&J(u)=\int_{0}^{T}\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}}{V}}_{L}\,dx
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 & \dot{\vec{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}
                      \dot{x} \\
                      \dot{y} \\
                    \end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{f}(\vec{x}~,{u})=
 \begin{bmatrix}
            V\cos(\theta)+w_x(x,y) \\
            V\sin(\theta)+w_y(x,y)\\
          \end{bmatrix}\quad, u=\theta\,\quad, V =\rm constant\\          
%&L=\frac{\sqrt{{x'}^2+{y'}^2}}{V} \quad, (..)'=\frac{\partial (..)}{\partial u} \\   
\end{align*}
the Hamiltonian according to the above Wiki article is
\begin{align*}
 & H=\lambda_{{x}} \left( V\cos \left( \theta  \right) +w_{{x}} \left( x
,y \right)  \right) +\lambda_{{y}} \left( V\sin \left( \theta
 \right) +w_{{y}} \left( x,y \right) \right) +1\tag 1
\end{align*}
why is $~L~$ for this example equal one ?
$$L=\frac 1V\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}=\frac 1V\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}\right)^2}\ne 1 $$

$L(\vec{x}, u,t)$ represents the associated Lagrangian. Remember that the variable to minimize is $t$ or $\int_0^t 1 dt$.

The lagrangian is:
$$
L =\int_0^t \left(1 + \Lambda(\dot p - f(p,\theta))\right)dt
$$
with $\Lambda = (\lambda_x,\lambda_y)$, $p = (x,y)$ and $f(p,\theta) =\cases{V\cos\theta+u(p)\\ V\sin \theta+v(p)}$
Applying the Euler-Lagrange conditions we have
$$
\cases{\dot\Lambda - \Lambda f_{p}(p,\theta)=0\\
V(-\lambda_x\sin\theta+\lambda_y\cos\theta) = 0
}
$$
and now solving for $\Lambda$,
$$
\Lambda = \cases{-\frac{\cos\theta}{V+u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta}\\ -\frac{\sin\theta}{V+u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta}}
$$
Substituting into $\dot\Lambda - \Lambda f_{p}(p,\theta)=0$ we obtain
$$
\dot\theta = v_x\sin^2\theta+(u_x-v_y)\sin\theta\cos\theta-u_y\cos^2\theta
$$
hence, de movement is described by the system
$$
\cases{
\dot p = f(p,\theta)\\
\dot\theta = v_x\sin^2\theta+(u_x-v_y)\sin\theta\cos\theta-u_y\cos^2\theta
}
$$
Note that if $u$ and $v$ are constant, then $\theta=c$ which means that the minimum time paths are straight lines.
NOTE
$$
\dot\Lambda - \Lambda f_{p}(p,\theta)\Rightarrow \cases{\dot \lambda_x = -\lambda_x u_x-\lambda_y v_x\\ \dot \lambda_y = -\lambda_x u_y -\lambda_y v_y}
$$
and as  $\cases{\lambda_x=-\frac{\cos\theta}{V+u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta}\\ \lambda_y = -\frac{\sin\theta}{V+u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta}\\ \lambda_y = \lambda_x\tan\theta }$ we can develop the ode involving $\theta$ by substitution:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\tan\theta\lambda_y\right)=-\left(-\frac{\cos\theta}{V+u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta}\right)u_x-\left(-\frac{\sin\theta}{V+u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta}\right)v_y
$$
Follows a MATHEMATICA script which finds through the due substitutions, the $\theta$ ode. This can be done also using any symbolic processor as MACSYMA or MAXIMA.
Clear[dlx, lx, ly]
lx = -Cos[theta[t]]/d;
ly = -Sin[theta[t]]/d;
dlx = -(lx ux + ly vx);
odetheta = Sec[theta[t]]^2 theta'[t] lx + Tan[theta[t]] dlx - dlx //FullSimplify // Numerator;
Solve[odetheta == 0, theta'[t]][[1]] // Expand


we want to minimize the time that take object to move from  A to be B $~\int_0^T,dt=\int_0^T\frac{ds}{v}=\int_0^T\frac{\sqrt{1+y'}}{v},dx$ did you read the Wiki article ?

Did you see in the article, the general solution?

Note that the $J(u)$ and the $H$ are two distinct formulations about the same problem...

O.k I see   Thank you

" and now solving for $~\Lambda~$" these are 3  equations , which 2 equation you use ?
Substituting into $\dot\Lambda - \Lambda f_{p}(p,\theta)=0$ we obtain ?
these are 2 equations for $~\dot\theta~$ ??

Please. See attached note.

$~\frac{d}{dt} (\cot(\theta)\lambda_y)~$ ? and $~v_y\mapsto v_x~$

Please. Again see an attached comment.

Thank you again
